# Change text position - BigCommerce banner

Tags: css, bigcommerce, banner

Working with Chelsea Warm, BigCommerce theme. I was able to adjust the padding around the promotional banner (see screenshot), with the following code, added to Storefront>Footer Scripts in the control panel:

```
`<style>
    .banner.rte {
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>`
```

But I need the text to be centered in the banner (it's near the bottom instead and looks off-balance). Anyone know a good tweak for this?

Best, YT

[Screenshot of header - link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu9hG.png)

Comment: please paste your website link here with preview code

Comment: Hi R.K., here it is: https://store-99kktb89st.mybigcommerce.com/                                   
preview code: piorct2dj9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so here is the css you need to put into your css file

```
.banner strong {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 22px;
}
```

and it will look like this :

[image]

Thanks